# porting a fullscreen app from Tkinter to Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote a dashboard application in `Tkinter`, basically a fullscreen app with a few `tk.Label` in a grid, updated with various information.

I now want to recode this in `Kivy` but I have some problems understanding the change in philosophy.

The `Tkinter` skeleton is

```
class Dashboard(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root = parent.root
        self.timestr = tk.Label(self.root)
        self.timestr.configure(...)
(...)
```

I then `.configure()` various things (font, text tabel, etc.)

In `Kivy` I want to change the design by creating several `FloatLayout` widgets, equivelent to the `tk.Label` above. I have so far

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Time(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = "xx:xx"

    def update(self):
        self.time = "9:53"

class Dashboard(Widget):
    Time()

class DashApp(App):
    def build(self):
        dash = Dashboard()
        return dash

Window.fullscreen = True
DashApp().run()
```

with the relavant `kv` file:

```
#:kivy 1.8.0
<Time>:
    size: root.width, root.height / 4
    pos: 0, 0
    Label:
        center_x: self.width / 2
        top: self.top - 5
        font_size: 70
        text: "aaa"
```

Upon launching the app it goes fullscreen but is empty.

How should I express the fact that I want to instantiate a `Dashboad()` and then within it some widgets (`Time()` for instance)?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Dashboard(Widget):
    Time()
```

I think you have a misconception about what this does - that being, nothing. The `Time` object is instantiated but not added to the `Dashboard` or anything. That's why your app is blank, it's just a `Dashboard` widget that is itself blank.

You instead need to add the `Time` widget to the dashboard, e.g. in the `__init__`:

```
class Dashboard(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Dashboard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Time())
```

Since you always want to do this, it's even easier and better to do it with a kv rule:

```
<DashBoard>:
    Time:
```

You'll also have some messed up positioning right now, but it looks like you're still experimenting with that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Label `center_x` being `self.width/2`, which I think refers to the label itself, try `root.width/2`, which I believe refers to the root widget, in this case, `Time`.

I'm quite sure, that in the kv file, `root` generally refers to the widget between these `<>`(that is the root parent of whatever you are tweaking at the time), `self` refers to the **current** widget, and `app` refers to the app instance.